# how to present JSON output in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I want to present a large JSON Output from Apex class in salesforce to frontend.
At frontend it could be in html or table format.
I want a view that is simple and easy to comprehend.

I tried using LWC and Flexcards but I am new to the salesforce technology

Comment: can you share the (anonymised if needed) JSON sample? Or what have you tried? If it's generally an array of objects with simple fields (no/little nesting) - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable should be perfect. If it's a nested tree-like structure there's `lightning-tree` and `lightning-tree-grid`. Or maybe open-close sections of custom html so look into `accordion`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use a [standard lightning data table](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example).

It will allow you to easily display the data for the users and it might just be what you are looking for, as long as you don't need to add particular rows customization.

You only need to feed it the list of items, list of fields to display and a key field